# Should I serve a customized sitemap to Baidu that only contains URLs with Chinese content?

Tags: seo, sitemap, multilingual, language, baidu

I'm working on a multilingual website which has Chinese as one of the supported languages. I have a sitemap that includes links to all the pages on the website.

Should I serve to the Baidu bot a different version of the sitemap that only has the Chinese content links? I'm specifically asking because I read somewhere that Baidu only targets the Chinese content.